# How do you query several tables at once given a list of table names as strings?

Tags: c#, linq

So I work at a company where there are several tables with different names, but the exact same structure (date, time, value).  What I would like to be able to do is have my program (C# or LINQ/LINQPad) run through these tables and query out a specific row so I can make sure they have all been updated properly.  Is this doable?

So far my train of thought has been this. Knowing that each table name will give it a different class, I'm trying to generically get the values out of the table.  I am able to get the table by using the code here

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
var myTable = (ITable)dc.GetType().GetProperty("Table").GetValue(dc, null);
```

My problem is I'm trying to get the columns out of this table using a similar method.  However, the below is throwing an error:

```
foreach(var e in myTable)
{
    double myValue = (double)e.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(e, null);
}
```

So when I took a look all the properties of e.GetType(), I noticed it had 2, one of which was Context, so I went exploring there.  However, the next layer down seems to be a dead end of metadata with no actual data coming out of my loop.  Am I even heading in the right direction?  Once I get this hurdle, it would be easy enough for me to make a list and get my results out that way.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Something like `foos.Select(f => new CommonModel { Source = 'foos', X = f.X, Y = f.Y }).Union(bars.Select(b => new CommonModel { Source = 'bars', X = b.X, Y = b.Y })` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query many tables by primary key (EntityKey in db context), then
`ObjectContext` has a method called `GetObjectByKey` that allows you to get object by `EntityKey`
So, you need to construct just a EntityKey. According to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykey(v=vs.110).aspx), it is pretty simple,

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
EntityKey key = new EntityKey("DataContext.Table","Id", 123);
dynamic entity = dc.GetObjectByKey(key);
```

You can create an interface that is common for all tables (entites) that have the same structure and cast your object to the interface, or just use `dynamic`.